# maven plugin detect hudson

Tags: maven, hudson, maven-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for maven and I want find out, if it runs on hudson. Then I want to know which user triggered the build.

Is there an API (@component) that provides access to this?

Comment: Do you want to find out if running the build on hudson (with module included) actually works or do you want to get notified when your plugin is executed on hudson? I'm curious what you intend to use this for.

Comment: The plugin should find out, if it is called from hudson. And it should be able to ask hudson some questions about the current running build (for example the build trigger)

Comment: a dirty workaround is parsing the api of hudson http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API

Comment: Usually during a run in Hudson some environment variables exists like HUDSON_ID etc. which you can use to detect if running in Hudson, but it sounds a little bit strange why a plugin needs to know if it's running within Hudson?

Answer (score 0):

Usually during a run in Hudson some environment variables exists like [JOB_ID](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-HudsonSetEnvironmentVariables) etc. which you can use to detect if running in Hudson.

Comment: I will change my question a bit, because just to know that somewhere out there running a hudson is not enough. I want to talk with him.

Comment: Than use the already mentioned [REST API](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API)

Comment: If a plugin is already part of a build, there must be an direct API somewhere.

Comment: You seemed to misunderstand things in relationship with Hudson/Jenkins. Jenkins/Hudson start a build which forking a process which means there is no direct api to talk to Jenkins/Hudson during the build. The other question is what you like to achieve if you are talking with Jenkins/Hudson during a Maven build? May be you can elaborate your question more to get a better view of what you like to do.

Comment: I want to access the same information as offered by the API. But I think it is not the clean way to use the API if you're already part of a process. Especially because the API is not always available.